# .Net Core BadGateway Error when huge data in post response

Tags: c#, soap, async-await, .net-core, httpclient

I am trying to do a soaprequest to a webservice, it runs for little data but get a badGateway error when trynig for huge data,

here is my code

```
var content = new StringContent(soapEnvelopRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
using (var response = await client.PostAsync(action, content))
{
  var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  return soapResponse;
}
```

Comment: Please look at your proxy (nginx, for instance), it is not look as .Net Core issue

Comment: there is no proxy, before i used HttpWebRequest with .Net 4.5 and it ran so fine, and after i migrate to !.net core i am actually using httpClient the post request is running when the response is a little string but not working when it's a large string

Comment: Issue fixed by adding  a web.config file (it dosn't exist by default because i am using vs2017) and add configuration of TTL
    `<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:30:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />`